# Multiple Shader Programs to give different textures

Tags: webgl

little lost here. trying to set different textures on different vertices. WebGL makes this extremely unnecessarily difficult. Basically I have a text file with matrices of the vertices I want, which works. (example here: http://jdmdev.net/Foundation/index.html)

But to now set different textures I would need to do something called 'texture atlassing' which there is absolutely zero documentation on how to implement that online... anywhere.

I am very new to WebGL but have an extensive programming background so I am able to understand any concepts given to me.. if I can just see something working or at the very least some documentation on it.

So I think texture atlassing is out of the picture. However, if I am understadning the WebGL pipeline as well as I think I am. Can't I just create multiple shader/vertex programs? If so, how can I go about that? I don't need a direct example, but just some code will do wonders. I just need to see this one time and I will get it, but it's impossible to find any useful stuff on the web, due to this being so new. I appreciate any help given.

Not sure how any code would help with answering this question, but here's my code that I basically used from learningwebgltutorials.com

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler2;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    }
</script>

<script id="shader2-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler2;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    }
</script>

<script id="shader2-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var gl;

    function initGL(canvas) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
            gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
        } catch (e) {
        }
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
        }
    }


    function getShader(gl, id) {
        var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!shaderScript) {
            return null;
        }

        var str = "";
        var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
        while (k) {
            if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                str += k.textContent;
            }
            k = k.nextSibling;
        }

        var shader;
        if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }


    var shaderProgram;

    function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
        shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
    }


    function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    }


    var mudTexture;
    var rockTexture;

    function initTexture() {
        mudTexture = gl.createTexture();
        mudTexture.image = new Image();
        mudTexture.image.onload = function () {
            handleLoadedTexture(mudTexture)
        }

        mudTexture.image.src = "mud.gif";

        rockTexture = gl.createTexture();
        rockTexture.image = new Image();
        rockTexture.image.onload = function () {
            handleLoadedTexture(rockTexture)
        }

        rockTexture.image.src = "rockstar.gif";
    }


    var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
    var mvMatrixStack = [];
    var pMatrix = mat4.create();

    function mvPushMatrix() {
        var copy = mat4.create();
        mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
        mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
    }

    function mvPopMatrix() {
        if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
            throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
        }
        mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
    }


    function setMatrixUniforms() {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    }


    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }



    var currentlyPressedKeys = {};

    function handleKeyDown(event) {
        currentlyPressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;
    }


    function handleKeyUp(event) {
        currentlyPressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;
    }


    var pitch = 0;
    var pitchRate = 0;

    var yaw = 0;
    var yawRate = 0;

    var xPos = 10;
    var yPos = 0.4;
    var zPos = 10;

    var speed = 0;

    function handleKeys() {
        if (currentlyPressedKeys[33]) {
            // Page Up
            pitchRate = 0.1;
        } else if (currentlyPressedKeys[34]) {
            // Page Down
            pitchRate = -0.1;
        } else {
            pitchRate = 0;
        }

        if (currentlyPressedKeys[37] || currentlyPressedKeys[65]) {
            // Left cursor key or A
            yawRate = 0.1;
        } else if (currentlyPressedKeys[39] || currentlyPressedKeys[68]) {
            // Right cursor key or D
            yawRate = -0.1;
        } else {
            yawRate = 0;
        }

        if (currentlyPressedKeys[38] || currentlyPressedKeys[87]) {
            // Up cursor key or W
            speed = 0.01;
        } else if (currentlyPressedKeys[40] || currentlyPressedKeys[83]) {
            // Down cursor key
            speed = -0.01;
        } else {
            speed = 0;
        }

    }


    var worldVertexPositionBuffer = null;
    var worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer = null;

    function handleLoadedWorld(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        var vertexCount = 0;
        var vertexPositions = [];
        var vertexTextureCoords = [];
        for (var i in lines) {
            var vals = lines[i].replace(/^\s+/, "").split(/\s+/);
            if (vals.length == 6 && vals[0] != "//") {
                // It is a line describing a vertex; get X, Y and Z first
                vertexPositions.push(parseFloat(vals[0]));
                vertexPositions.push(parseFloat(vals[1]));
                vertexPositions.push(parseFloat(vals[2]));
                //document.write(vertexPositions[0]);
                // And then the texture coords
                vertexTextureCoords.push(parseFloat(vals[3]));
                vertexTextureCoords.push(parseFloat(vals[4]));
                //document.write(vals[4]) + "<br/>");
                vertexCount += 1;
            }
        }

        worldVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexPositions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        worldVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        worldVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = vertexCount;

        worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexTextureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
        worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = vertexCount;

        document.getElementById("loadingtext").textContent = "";
    }


    function loadWorld() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "world.txt");
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                handleLoadedWorld(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }

    function loadTextureValues() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "world.txt");
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
               getCorrectTexture(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }

    var matchWithTexture = {};

    function getCorrectTexture(data)
    {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        var vertexCount = 0;
        var vertexTextureValueCoords = [];

        for (var i in lines) {
            var vals = lines[i].replace(/^\s+/, "").split(/\s+/);
            if (vals.length == 6 && vals[0] != "//") 
            {
                //document.write(vertexTextureValueCoords.push(parseFloat(vals[1])) + "</br>");
                vertexTextureValueCoords.push(parseFloat(vals[5]));
                matchWithTexture[vertexCount] = vertexTextureValueCoords[vertexCount];
                vertexCount++;
            }
        }
    }



    function drawScene() {
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer == null || worldVertexPositionBuffer == null) {
            return;
        }

        mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(-pitch), [1, 0, 0]);
        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(-yaw), [0, 1, 0]);
        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-xPos, -yPos, -zPos]);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, mudTexture);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, rockTexture);

        loadTextureValues();
        for(var key in matchWithTexture)
        {
            //document.write(matchWithTexture[key] + "<br/>");
            if(matchWithTexture[key] == 1)
            {
                gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
            }
            else {
                gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 1);
            }
        }



        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, worldVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, worldVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
    }


    var lastTime = 0;
    // Used to make us "jog" up and down as we move forward.
    var joggingAngle = 0;

    function animate() {
        var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        if (lastTime != 0) {
            var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

            if (speed != 0) {
                xPos -= Math.sin(degToRad(yaw)) * speed * elapsed;
                zPos -= Math.cos(degToRad(yaw)) * speed * elapsed;

                joggingAngle += elapsed * 0.6; // 0.6 "fiddle factor" - makes it feel more realistic :-)
                yPos = Math.sin(degToRad(joggingAngle)) / 20 + 0.4
            }

            yaw += yawRate * elapsed;
            pitch += pitchRate * elapsed;

        }
        lastTime = timeNow;
    }


    function tick() {
        requestAnimFrame(tick);
        handleKeys();
        drawScene();
        animate();
    }



    function webGLStart() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson10-canvas");
        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders();
        initTexture();
        loadWorld();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
        document.onkeyup = handleKeyUp;

        tick();
    }

</script>
```

So all I did was create a 2nd shader/vertex program, and it still works. So how can I go about implementing them with different information from the first shader/vertex programs?

And a last question would be: would it just be worth it more to use a library instead of trying to do everything in webgl? I mean, with all the google searches I have done on webgl, most of all the examples/tutorials are all done using three.js, or babylon.js..etc. I'm just wondering if it's even worth it to try to do what I am doing. I guess what the question would be is, would professional settings want me to do straight up webgl, or would I (most likely) be using a library? I don't ever even plan on programming webgl, but just to know if it ever comes up in an interview.

**SOLUTION VIA NO-TEXTURE ALIASING**

https://github.com/jordmax12/WebGL/blob/master/Foundation%205/foundation_2.js

Since I was already parsing information from a text file for vertices and texture coordinates, there MUST be a way to do this for the texture itself (without texture aliasing).

Comment: There's [a simple example of texture atlasing at the bottom of this page describing how to texture a cube with 6 faces](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). You use texture coordinates to choose which part of texture maps to which vertices. So any triangle can select a different part of the texture. Note that means if 2 adjacent triangles use different texture those triangles do NOT share vertices. That's because a vertex consists of both a position and texture coords and since the tex coords have to be different the verts can't be shared.

Comment: @gman Cool! Actually I figured out a way to parse a simple text file, and have it bind a texture to that without atlasing at all. I'll post the link in my question, in case anyone wants to do this as well. I feel it's a lot easier, and more 'programmy'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different textures and shaders on different vertices if you draw them one by one. The problem is that this is quite inefficient. So for good performance, I don't think there is a way around atlasing -- that's why everybody is doing this.

I am not aware of any three.js util to simplify atlasing (but I am not very familiar with three.js).

It should be straight forward to implement a utility that draws the textures to a big canvas, creating the atlas on the fly at runtime and keeping track of the coordinates. After setup, the tool would basically transform coordinates and texture names or ids to a pure coordinate array (including texture coordinates).

Whether you should use a library really depends on what you plan to do. If a retained mode API works for your use case, it's probably a good idea and more convenient to use three.js.

Comment: would you happen to have an example of your own, or possibly some resource that you used to create one? I can wrap my head around ai pathfinding and cpu poker betting algorithms, but there's literally nothing that I've found to show me how to do what you're describing, but what you are describing is exactly what i am trying to do.